# Asp.Net MVC keep logs for CRUD functions

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my mvc application i have a base model as below

```
namespace ModulericaV1.Models
{
    public class BaseModel 
    {      
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        public DateTime? CrDate { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CrUser")]
        public ApplicationUser UserCr { get; set; }
        public string CrUser { get; set; }

        public DateTime? MdDate { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("MdUser")]
        public ApplicationUser UserMd { get; set; }
        public string MdUser { get; set; }

        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        public ApplicationUser GetUserObject(string id) 
        {
            var UserObject = db.Users.Find(id);
            return UserObject;
        }


        public void LogBasic()
        {
            if (this.CrDate == null)
            {
                this.CrDate = System.DateTime.Now;
                this.CrUser = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
            }
            else
            {
                this.MdDate = System.DateTime.Now;
                this.MdUser = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All my models inherits the :BaseModel. What i am trying to do, calling LogBasic() method for all Create and Update DB queries so i can log which user create new row or made changes.

Where is the place should i need to call LogBasic() method .

Comment: Where are your create and update methods?

Comment: I have more than 30 models and each model has own create and update methods. But i dont want to call LogBasic() from each method. I want to call LogBasic() for each query which is more generic

Comment: I believe this is not the perfect design, you either have to have generic base create/update methods that calls the log method everytime or create base methods and call the base from the overriden create/update methods in each child every time.

Comment: To echo @stripthesoul, put the `ApplicationDbContext` in your controller. Embedding it in the model is a bad idea, as you have to create a new object every time to then retrieve it from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this should work:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext  : DbContext {

    // ... 

    public override int SaveChanges () {
        if(HasChanges()){
            foreach(var entry in Entries<BaseModel>()){
                ((BaseModel)entry.Entity).LogBasic();
            }
        }
    }

    // ... 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best place to do this is in the `ApplicationDbContext` on the `SaveChanges()` method. You can iterate through all of the items that are pending updates and then if they are of a `BaseModel`, log them.

I don't have the exact syntax to hand, but this is the idea:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    //.....

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
       foreach(var entity in this.ChangeTracker.Entries)
       {
          var baseModel = entity as BaseModel;

          if(baseModel!=null)
          {        
             switch(entity.State)
             {
                case State.Modified;
                // Do things with an updated version
                case State.Deleted:
                // Do things with the deleted version
                case State.Added:
                {
                   // Do things with the Added entity
                   baseModel.LogBasic();
                   break;
                }
             }
         }

       base.SaveChanges();
    }      
}
```